# Spring Security j_spring_security_check not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring WebApp using custom User, Roles, Permissions tables custom (read "naive") authentication.

I am migrating the code to use Spring Security now. I read tutorials and got to the point where my login.jsp page, css, js, png files can be accessed ANONYMOUSLY. I have a form with action attribute as "j_spring_security_check". On submitting the form the browser performs an HTTP Post to this URL which results in a 404.

Now I am not mapping j_spring_security_check using `RequestMapping`. Is that required? When should we have a request mapping for this URL?

In my authentication provider I provide a reference to a bean of a class which implements UserDetailsService. I am expecting Spring to perform the authentication by invoking loadUserByUserName but this method never gets invoked. Why is the method not invoked? Have I misunderstood how authentication should work? Do I need to provide a custom request mapping for j_spring_security_check to make it work?

Here is my Custom User Details Service:

```
@Service(value="myUserDetailsService")
public class LoginUserService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("here");

    User user = userRepository.findUser(username);
    if (user != null)
      return new V2VUserDetails(user);
    else
      return null;
  }

}
```

Here is my security XML:

```
    <http pattern="/**/*.css" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/**/*.js" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/**/*.png" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true">
      <intercept-url pattern="/login.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
      <form-login login-page="/login.html"
                  login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                  default-target-url="/welcomePage.html"
                  authentication-failure-url="/welcomePage.html"
                  always-use-default-target="true" />
    </http>

  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
  </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService"
    class="security.LoginUserService">
  </beans:bean>
```

I checked several answers on Stackoverflow and other sites but could not fix the problem.

**Edit**
Tried the suggestion given [here](http://bit.ly/13BmtER). Now getting BeanFactory not initialized error.

**Edit**
    
        contextConfigLocation
        /WEB-INF/security-v2v-servlet.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Update**

Current web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-v2v-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>v2v</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>v2v</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>v2v</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zip</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_check</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>UserAddFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
          filter.UserInfoAddToThreadFilter
      </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>UserAddFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>



    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Comment: Well I tried removing servlet mapping as you suggested but then it returns 404 for j_spring_security_check

Comment: Also ended up adding servlet mapping for j_spring_security_logout to make logout functionality work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a `@RequestMapping` for `/j_spring_security_check`, that pattern is intercepted by Spring Security Filter and should direct you to your login page.

My guess on what is going wrong is that probably the way you have set up the Spring Security Filter. You should have the following entries in your web.xml for your filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and the Security config file should be loaded up through Root Web application context - one loaded through `ContextLoaderListener` NOT the one through DispatcherServlet, eg:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/context-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If your configuration is along these lines, it should just work.

Comment: I have this in my config. It gets redirected to the login page just that the form-login submit does not work.

Comment: Wondering if this is relevant
http://mark.koli.ch/2010/07/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.html

Comment: Enabled spring security logs and see no activity on the logs on POST of j_spring_security_check.
Here are the configuration full files
https://github.com/C4G/V2V/tree/30df2edde69f1629b755c7d169353f52ceb9e25d/war/WEB-INF

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your issue then. Can you confirm your flow works without Spring security in place?

Comment: yes it works without spring security. Also works with the updated web.xml as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please ensure you have in the login form action `j_spring_security_check`
2. Not related to your problem but I recommend to remove the anonymous permission from `/j_spring_security_check` (remove the following line). Only the login form should have the anonymous permission. `<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />`

**Update**
Please remove from web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_check</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: With that the form goes to the page `localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check` and not `localhost:8080/app/j_spring_security_check`. Instead of my app's HTTP 404 page I see Apache's 404 page.

Comment: My understanding is the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter should be invoked on every web request that goes through the web app. Is that right? If so it should detect if the url j_spring_security_check is being accessed and should accordingly intercept the request and perform the authentication. It seems it is not doing so. Not seeing anything in the spring security DEBUG log during the POST on this url only suggests that tomcat feels that this URL is not published by my webapp and hence does not forward the request.

Comment: Having said that I think there is certainly a problem with servlet mapping in my web.xml.
Here is an online copy of the file
http://bit.ly/12fGrVh

Comment: So I got the request for j_spring_security_check to invoke my userDetailsService by creating a servlet mapping as follows:
`    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_check</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`
Is this a good way of doing it? How can I refine my servlet mappings in web.xml? What is the standard way of doing it? Could you please elaborate on these follow up questions?

Comment: My mistake - it should be without `/` only `j_spring_security_check`

Comment: You should not add the mapping to j_spring_security_check.
Please post  (by edit of the question) your web.xml

Comment: Added contents of web.xml to the question